# Mean number of replications in a birth-death process conditioned on extinction

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Background:** We begin with a population of one individual. Each individual has a probability $p$ to survive until it replicates into two independent and identical individuals.

Then the probability $\pi$ that the population ultimately goes extinct can be found by first step analysis over the first event:
$$
\pi=p\pi^2+1-p \quad\Rightarrow\quad \pi=\begin{cases}1, & p<\frac12 \\ p^{-1}-1, & p\geq\frac12.\end{cases}
$$

Likewise, if $p<\frac12$ such that extinction is assured, then the average number of replications $R$ that occur prior to extinction can be found by the same approach:
$$
R=p(2R+1) \quad\Rightarrow\quad R=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{p^{-1}-2}, & p<\frac12 \\ \infty, & p\geq\frac12,\end{cases}
$$

where the average number of replications $R$ is infinite if the extinction probability $\pi$ is nonzero. Instead, I would like to condition on extinction so that $R$ is always finite except at precisely $p=\frac12$.

**Question:** For $p>\frac12$, conditional on a population that ultimately goes extinct, what is the average number of replications $R$ that occur prior to extinction?

**Numerics:** In case it might be useful, I have simulated this birth-death process numerically and obtained the following table of $p$ and $R$ values:

[image: Table of Values]

Comment: When $p\geqslant\frac12$, the process of parameter $p$ conditioned by its extinction has the distribution of the process of parameter $1-p$. Thus, for every $p>\frac12$, $$E_p(R\mid\text{extinction})=E_{1-p}(R)=\frac{1-p}{1-2(1-p)}=\frac{1-p}{2p-1}$$

Comment: "I have simulated this birth-death process numerically and obtained the following table of $p$ and $R$ values" You really obtained these values of R *by numerical simulation*? Sorry but you have to show us how you did to obtain such a supernatural accuracy...

Comment: Hi Did, thank you for your answer! Your answer agrees with the numerical results, so it seems like it is correct. Would you mind explaining how you knew that the result would be symmetric about $p=\frac12$?

Comment: As for the accuracy of the numerical simulations, I used the following Matlab script, which runs in a matter of seconds: https://imgur.com/xjtCPjc

Comment: The result is not symmetric with respect to $p$, rather $P_p(\ \mid\text{extinction})=P_{1-p}$ for every $p\geqslant\frac12$.

Comment: I understand that you used that handy fact to derive your answer -- I am wondering if you might explain how you realized that $P_p(|extinction)=P_{1-p}$. It is not obvious to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is not obvious, one must compute $P_p(\text{given path}\mid\text{exptinction})$ to realize that it coincides with $P_{1-p}(\text{same path})$. For this, all that is needed is the value of $P_p(\text{extinction}\mid X_0=x)$ for every positive $x$.

Comment: Got it, thank you. The trick is recognizing that
$$P_p(R|extinction)=\frac{P_p(R)}{P_p(extinction)}=\frac{C_Rp^R(1-p)^{R+1}}{p^{-1}-1}=C_R(1-p)^Rp^{R+1}=P_{1-p}(R)$$
where $C_R$ is the $R$th Catalan number.